# How to use System.Net.WebClient() to download XML from a webservice with correctly encoded tags?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I'm using `System.Net.WebClient().DownloadFile()` to download the response of a webservice to a file. The response is rather large, so I don't use direct SOAP calls which would return a single string, eating up too much memory.
The response of the webservice is XML and what I get back is something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8?>
<string xmlns="MyAPI>
&lt;object name="First object"&gt;
...
```

So the issue is that the whole response gets wrapped into a "string" attribute and the real XML content gets encoded.
Without re-reading the whole saved file and converting everything back, how can I get the response in its original and correct format?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you believe that a web service call would take up too much memory. Did you try WCF?

Your problem is that you are calling the service the wrong way. You are no doubt using a GET HTTP request.

If you insist on not using a Service Reference, then I recommend you use WebRequest, and read the result through the GetResultStream() method. You could even process the result as XML by passing that stream into XmlReader.Create(Stream), which will return an XmlReader object that can be used to read the data without reading it all into memory.

Comment: It is taking too much memory because using SOAP and a service reference I get back _one_ string object which has 8 million characters. I'm running on an embedded device (iPhone) and there allocating an 8 million chars string (=16MB, b/c of unicode) can cause issues. WCF is unfortunately not an option but I will use it in future versions. Currently I'm using WebClient() - WebRequest is just mor work. Both, however return the same result: the tags are encoded, so back to my question. :-)

Comment: Please post the signature of the service. Does it return a `string`? Is it a service you created?

Comment: Yes, created by me. And yes, it returns a string.

Comment: If you wanted to return XML, then why is the return type `string` instead of `XElement` or `XmlElement`? If the return type is `string`, then it _must_ be encoded.

Comment: I don't know! Maybe it has grown historically. I can't do anything about this. That was maybe unclear. When I said I did create the service I meant, I referenced it. Fact is: it is returning a string. Fact is: the string contains XML. Fact is: if I use a regular SOAP call I can load the returned string (XML) directly into an XmlDocument. If I do a normal web request I get back the same response but embedded in a "string" tag and the tag's content - the XML - is HTML encoded.

Comment: Actually, even when you do the SOAP call, the string is encoded and embedded in some tags. It's just that it gets decoded for you. You should compare the network traffic between the SOAP call and the WebClient call. Use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) or something like it.